# Laravel passport can't find ApproveAuthorizationController

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I'm trying to setup a laravel application with oauth autorization by using the laravel passport functionality. I'm using the official tutorial (https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport). But now if I make a post request to '/oauth/authorize' the following error message occurs:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController does not exist
```

I don't know what I've been doing wrong. I use the routes getting from 'Passport:routes' and no self defined routes.

I've already made a composer update, install and clear cache but nothing worked.

The problem get caused here:

```
/**
 * Register the routes needed for authorization.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function forAuthorization()
{
    $this->router->group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function ($router) {
        $router->get('/authorize', [
            'uses' => 'AuthorizationController@authorize',
        ]);

        $router->post('/authorize', [
            'uses' => 'ApproveAuthorizationController@approve',
        ]);

        $router->delete('/authorize', [
            'uses' => 'DenyAuthorizationController@deny',
        ]);
    });
}
```

I've already tried it by importing the missing class with a use statement but it still wont work.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `use` statement at the top of a controller or service proivder. Somewhere you have a class being used with out properly importing it first. That's why you're seeing the concatenated string like:

```
App\Http\Controllers\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController.
```

I assume what you need is this:

```
use Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController;
```

or `Passport` in `Passport::routes` is not being imported, one of the two. In `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

Comment: I found the place in the code where the problem starts. (I've edited the question)

Comment: Try deleting `services.php` and `packages.php` from `bootstrap/cache` and rerunning `composer dumpautoload`